# What is CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(RADIAN) exactly doing?

Tags: iphone, core-animation

I don't really understand what this function is good for. Can someone explain that (maybe with some examples)?

Can I rotate an UIImageView object with this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CGAffineTransformMakeRotation is a constructor that creates you a rotation matrix, like CGPointMake, or NSMakePoint.  Some functions requires you to pass in a transformation matrix like:

```
 
void CGPathAddArc (
   CGMutablePathRef path,
   const CGAffineTransform *m,
   CGFloat x,
   CGFloat y,
   CGFloat radius,
   CGFloat startAngle,
   CGFloat endAngle,
   bool clockwise
);
```

You can use [UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/1623918-uigraphicsgetcurrentcontext) to get a [CGContextRef](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgcontextref) and transform/rotate the context as you like.

**UPDATE**: You can directly change UIView's transform.  It is a property:
@property(nonatomic) CGAffineTransform transform.
Thanks to Brad for pointing this out.

Comment: Actually, you can directly rotate a UIView using the CGAffineTransform struct produced by CGAffineTransformMakeRotation().  You just set the UIView's transform property to the new CGAffineTransform and it will be rotated.